# How client knows the session of logged in user in .net 7 web api?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an angular as client side and .net 7 web api application, I am using JWT Token for authentication. There can be multiple users logged in at a time. I am not getting how .net 7 internally knows which user session to be used for particular user.

Comment: This generally has nothing to do with the API, can you please elaborate on how you are identifying the user session, that will help focus this question. Or are you asking how you _can_ identify the sessions?

Comment: Short answer: by using headers, first request with a particular user-agent and IP-address gets some unique identifier, then this identifier does round-trips. After authentication extra headers are added (token with claims data, some others may be). Http itself is all about headers.

Comment: @Chris Schaller Yes, I want to identify which user sessions are there and how .net knows that when the request is coming in from particular use.

Comment: Do you need to differentiate between different user sessions, or specifically do you want to try and enforce single session per user? The Angular Client "knows" implcitly the session, it controls the session, so the question is a bit ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

In an Angular and .NET 7 Web API application using JWT Token for authentication, the .NET runtime internally uses the `HttpContext` object to handle individual HTTP requests and responses. This object encapsulates all the information related to an individual HTTP request, including the JWT token, request headers, and decoded token information like claims.

When a user makes a request to the Web API, the JWT token is typically included in the request headers. The .NET runtime automatically parses the request headers and extracts the JWT token. It then decodes the token to retrieve the associated user information, such as user ID or username, and any additional claims included in the token.

The `HttpContext` object contains the decoded token information, allowing you to access it within your API controllers or middleware. You can access the user's information and claims using properties like `User.Identity.Name` or `User.Claims`.

It's important to note that the `HttpContext` object is transient and specific to each individual request. This means that for each request, the .NET runtime creates a new instance of the `HttpContext` object and populates it with the relevant information for that particular request.

By using the `HttpContext` object, the .NET runtime is able to keep track of the user session and associate the correct token and user information with each request. This allows your Web API to handle multiple users logged in at the same time, as each request will have its own `HttpContext` object with the appropriate user information.

Overall, the `HttpContext` object plays a crucial role in managing authentication and authorization in your Angular and .NET 7 Web API application by providing access to the JWT token and decoded user information for each individual request.

Comment: Ok got it. Can you also tell, If I am not using JWT tokens then what .net 7 will do ? How it will identify the session internally ?